# Scrapy - wait for Splash to finish?

Tags: python, scrapy, splash-screen

The below is a simplified version of my code. When run, the text 'FINISHED' prints a long time before 'RUNNING':

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class ExtractSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'extract'
    start_urls = ['SomeURL']

    def parse(self, response):

        url_list = response.css('a.title::attr(href)').extract()
        for url in url_list:
            splash_args = {
                        'html': 1,
                        'png': 1,
                        'render_all': True,
                        'wait': 0.5
                    }
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse_result, endpoint='render.json', args=splash_args)
        print('FINISHED')

    def parse_result(self, response):
        print('RUNNING')
```

I guess this has something to do with threads running in the background - but was wondering if there was any way to checking if the function has complete before moving onto the next code? For example, some sort of if statement before Print('FINISH')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapy uses asynchronous code (i.e. requests are treated independently), so there's IMHO no simple way to achieve this. You can only tell if one individual request is completed and that takes place in the `parse_result` method (if processed without error, of course).

Also, as a side note, in your example you wouldn't get *FINISHED* ever printed after *RUNNING* just considering the way generators work. Look at the simplest example:

```
>>> def foo():
...   for i in range(5):
...     yield i
...   print 'Finished'
>>>
>>> [x for x in foo()]
Finished
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```